# Turtle graphics window does not appear vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, turtle-graphics, python-3.9

I am using vscode. Only a simple turtle statement can show the graphic window effect.
Why can't the graphics windows be displayed?

```
from turtle import *

def star(sidelength):
    '''Draws a 5-pointed star of a
    given sidelength'''
    for i in range(5):
        forward(sidelength)
        right(144) #why this angle??

def starSpiral():
    '''Draws a spiral of stars'''
    length = 5
    for i in range(60):
        star(length)
        right(5)
        length += 5
```

After running, nothing came out.

Comment: if this is all your code, nothing will happen because you don't call the functions

Comment: I learned later, thanks everyone. star(100), starspiral().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the information you provided, I ran it on my computer and modified the code:

1.**Draws a 5-pointed star of a given sidelength:**

For drawing a five-pointed star with a given side length, we need to give it an input value:

```
import turtle
def star():
    sidelength = int(input("Please input sidelength："))
    turtle.begin_fill()
    i = 1
    for i in range(5):
        turtle.forward(sidelength)
        turtle.right(144)
        i += 1
turtle.end_fill()
star()
```

Run:

[image]

2. **Draws a spiral of stars:**

> ```
> import turtle   
> def starSpiral():
>     '''Draws a spiral of stars'''
>     for i in range(60):
>         turtle.forward(5*i)
>         turtle.left(144)
> starSpiral()
> ```

run:

[image]

3. **About "right(144) #why this angle?":**

   It means to turn 144 degrees to the right, because each angle of the five-pointed star is 36 degrees, so the angle we need to rotate when drawing is `180-36=144` degree.

Comment: Good, now I have learned, thank you. I am very clear about example 2 you provided.